# What library to use to *write* XML file in a C++ program?

Tags: c++, xml

What library to use to *write* XML file in a C++ program?

I've found two classes posted in CodeProject

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/stl/simple_xmlwriter.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/XML_writer.aspx

but want to check if there is more standard option than these. I'm only concerned with writing, and not parsing XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried different libraries and finally decided for [TinyXml](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/index.html). It's compact, fast, free (zlib license) and very easy to use.

Comment: Would you please briefly introduce the main reason you chose TinyXml rather than Xerces-c?

Comment: I've used TinyXML too it's lightweight and has a licence allowing it to be used in commercial apps.  Very convenient if you need a 1 file parser/generator

Comment: The reason I chose TinyXML is because it had the features I needed. I haven't run into an XML file that I cannot read. More importantly, the size and that I could easily embed into my own application without worrying about another DLL (e.g., Xerces = ~18MB).

Comment: not related exclusively to XML, but is there any way to generate an output file based on grammar containers? something in STD or boost?

Answer (score 4):

Question: Are you ever going to update an XML file? Because while that sounds like it's just more writing, with XML it still requires a parser.

While xerces is large and bloated, it is fully standards compliant and it is DOM based. Should you ever have to cross platform or change language, there will always be a DOM based library for whatever language/platform you might move to so knowing how DOM based parsing/writing works is a benefit. If you are going to use XML, you may as well use it correctly.

Avoiding XML altogether is of course the best option. But short of that, I'd go with xerces.

Comment: Would you please briefly explain why you think avoiding XML is the better if possible? (The data generated by a program stored in XML format will be well defined, and (arguably) better than in a plaintext file?)

Comment: XML is bloated, is easy to break, and is extremely human unfriendly. Non-programmers cannot easily deal with XML without programmatic help. Data formats like JSON, YAML and even the .INI format are much more compact and easier to modify by hand, even by non-programmers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Xerces-C++, a library written by Apache foundation. This library permits read, write and manipulate XML files.

Link: http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/

Answer (score 0):

For my purposes, PugiXML worked out really nicely

http://pugixml.org/

The reason why I thought it was so nice was because it was simply 3 files, a configuration header, a header, and the actual source.

But as you stated, you aren't interested in parsing, so why even bother using a special class to write out XML? While maybe your classes are too complex for this, I found the easy thing to do is use the `std::ostream` and just write out standard compliant XML this way. For example, say I have a class that represents a `Company` which is a collection of `Employee` objects, just make a method in each the `Company` and `Employee` classes that looks something like the following psuedocode

```
Company::writeXML(std::ostream& out){
    out << "<company>" << std::endl;
    BOOST_FOREACH(Employee e, employees){
        e.writeXML(out);
    }
    out << "</company>" << std::endl;
}
```

and to make it even easier, your `Employee`'s writeXML function can be declared `virtual` so that you can have a specific output for say a `CEO`, `President`, `Janitor` or whatever the subclasses should be.

Comment: THanks for suggestion. I've basically considered this option. I.e. piggybacking the code in the two links in the original post and do something like you described here. But I was concerned with the longer term extensibility of the code, and wonder if considering using more standard library for XML processing is useful.

Comment: Anybody can provide some comparison between TinyXML and pugixml libraries?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the open-source [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org) library for years, works great for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and wound up [rolling my own solution](http://tlzprgmr.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/an-xml-writer-for-c/). It's implemented as a single header file that you can drop into your project: [xml_writer.h](http://code.google.com/p/xml-writer-cpp/source/browse/trunk/xml_writer.h)

And it comes with a set of [unit tests](http://code.google.com/p/xml-writer-cpp/source/browse/trunk/xml_writer.cpp) which also serve as documentation.

Answer (score -1):

#### Roll your own

I've been in a similar situation.  I had a program that needed to generate JSON.  We did it two ways.  First we tried [jsoncpp](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/), but in the end I just generated the JSON directly via a `std::ofstream`.

Afterward we ran the generated JSON through a validator to catch any syntax errors.  There were a few but they were really easy to find and correct.

If I were to do it again I would definitely roll my own again.  Somewhat unexpectedly, there was less code when using `std::ofstream`.  Plus we didn't have to use/learn a new API.  It was easier to write and is easier to maintain.

Comment: If I do what you suggest, I suspect what I can create, to some extent, is going to end up reinventing the wheel made available by some existing code like the two links I gave above, or libraries like TinyXML and Xerces. It's a trade off between development time and learning time, and controllability versus the extent of piggybacking on others' reusable code.

Comment: I would normally advocate rolling your own for most simple input/output scenarios. (Believe me, I hate taking dependencies on anything I can do better myself). But I've seen too many smart developers screw-up basic XML by trying to roll their own with spritntf statements.T here's too many free XML libraries for C/C++ out there to consider before going it alone. That and every OS language combination has some native XML thing going for it. I'm not saying your JSON solution is wrong - as you did have some test validation for it - but XML code can get buggy if you don't pay attention.

Comment: I definitely would not advocate rolling your own if you didn't do some validation testing on the output.  I also would *never* parse XML or JSON by hand, even if it was simple.  When you're only dealing with output (and the format isn't too complex or dynamic), just printing out the structure is usually so easy that it ought to be considered.

Comment: You never know who will want to read your XML. Generate it with a known library. Rolling your own is just asking for problems down the road.

Comment: @jmucchiello That is why you validate the output.  Build a schema, and use a schema validator to ensure that the output is well formed.  Honestly XML is not that hard to ***generate***.

Comment: IME, handspun XML has no schema when the handspinning is performed. And later someone has to go in and "fix" it to make it validate. Maintenance friendly code uses a standard library when available.

I know XML isn't hard to generate. I also have had to support 10 different hand generated XML formats with no common code between them in a big project. How do I know all 10 were schema validated? So sure, roll your own. But don't RECOMMEND roll your own on this kind of website as you never know when you will be the one who has to fix it later. :)